# add elements to specific index in ArrayList or ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, arraylist

This maybe looks stupid and/or easy question but I couldn't done this.

I'm getting data from database (only). I need get both `element` and its `id` at the same time. For example,

```
+----------------+
|  id | username |
+----------------+
| 1   | user1    |
| 12  | user2    |
| 103 | user3    |
+----------------+
```

When I populate the `ArrayList` or `ArrayAdapter` (or maybe something else), I want to get the both `id` and `username`.

I tried to use `add(int index, String object)` method in ArrayList and `insert(String object, int index)` method in ArrayAdapter. But the both methods return me same error:

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 12, size is 1

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: can you post the code ??

Comment: I added an answer, something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used the `12` index, who doesn't exist. If you want add an element to the end, you might use this signature:

```
objectOfArrayList.add(strigObject); // add an element to end
```

And, you must always check size of array:

```
int index = 16;
if (objectOfArrayList.size() > index) {
    objectOfArrayList.add(index -1, stringObject); // add an element to position
}
```

There was performed checking for adding or inserting value to object of `ArrayList`:

> ```
> private void rangeCheckForAdd(int index) {
>     if (index > size || index < 0)
>         throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(outOfBoundsMsg(index));
> }
> ```

**UPDATE:**

If you need a structure "`key` - `value`" (the idea proposed by [Vitaliy Tsvayer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1618118/vitaliy-tsvayer)), you'll use map:

```
// id - user
LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put(1, "user1");
map.put(12, "user2");
map.put(103, "user3");
```

---

*Answer to question in the comments:*

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put("user", 1);
int id = map.get("user");
System.out.println("id = " + id); // "id = 1"
```

It will probably be appeared `java.lang.NullPointerException` in the last example , if key doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks. But if there's only 3 records, then it'll not add the element? 
I tried it, but not solved my problem. 

Sorry for late reply...

Comment: @MirjalalTalishinski, for these goals used `map`

Comment: @AndrewTobilko you mean look at tsvayer's answer?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko so, how can I get this key (id) value for specific user ?
For example I want to get `12` if I entered `user2` ?

Answer (score 0):

the reason that you are getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBound` exception is that first you are inserting `1` in index `1`.
but then directly trying to insert `12`.
but at that time the size of the list is only `1`.

my suggestion, use `HashMap`..
where you store ids as key and username as value i.e.

```
Map<String, String> = new HashMap <String, String>();
map.put('1', "name 1");
```